# How to relaunch cancelled Job?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to use coroutines instead of handlers. I have call which will refresh data every few seconds. It is called in `Job` object. When I leave app to background, I want to cancel this `Job`. When I come back to app I want to relaunch this job to do its work.

But once I cancel job, it will not relaunch ever again. Is there any way how to relaunch cancelled job? Because `isActive == false` even when I reinitialize variable

```
var job: Job? = null

job = launch {
    while (isActive){
    delay(5000)
    doStuff()
    }
}
```

When I pause my Activity I call `job?.cancel()` and `job = null`
When I enter Activity, I will call code above again. I thought I can reinitialize this job and launch refresh code again.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to restart a `cancel()`ed job. But this is easy enough to work around. Just start a new job instead. You could do it like this:

```
fun launchNewJob() = launch {
    while (isActive) {
        delay(5000)
        doStuff()
    }
}

job = launchNewJob()
```

`Job`s/coroutines are not heavy objects like `Thread`s, so you don't need to worry about creating new ones.

Comment: If this job is called within CoroutineScope, If I cancel it, will it cancel whole CoroutineScope and eventually killing all jobs running in that Scope or just this single job? Because `doStuff` is generic function called inside object extending CoroutineScope. If I cancel `job` it will cancel `doStuff` and also CoroutineScope of whole Activity which is extending it.

Comment: Cancelling a child job will not cancel the parent job. See second paragraph here: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/

Answer (score 5):

You can't "re-launch" the Job but you can create a new one, when you wrap the code inside:

```
var job = launch { jobFunction() }

fun jobFunction() {
    while (isActive){
      delay(5000)
      doStuff()
    }
}

if(job.isActive.not()) {
  job = launch( jobFunction() )
}
```